# Sample Online Data Algorithm Analysis

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, random, data-structures

I am going through a book called "Elements of Programming Interview" and have gotten stuck at the following problem:

> Implement an algorithm that takes as input an array of distinct
>   elements and a size, and returns a subset of the given size of the
>   array elements. All subsets should be equally likely. Return the
>   result in input array itself.

The solution they provide below is:

```
import random
def random_sampling(k, A):
    for i in range(k):
        # Generate a random index in [i, len(A) - 1].
        r = random.randint(i, len(A) - 1)
        A[i], A[r] = A[r], A[i]


A = [3, 7, 5, 11]
k = 3

print(random_sampling(k, A))
```

I so not understand what the authors are trying to do intuitively. Their explanation is below

> Another approach is to enumerate all subsets of size k and then select
>   one at random from these. Since there are (n to k) subsets of size k,
>   the time and space complexity are huge. The key to efficiently
>   building a random subset of size exactly k is to first build one of
>   size k - 1 and then adding one more element, selected randomly from
>   the rest. The problem is trivial when k = 1. We make one call to the
>   random number generator, take the returned value mod n (call it r),
>   and swap A[0] with A[r]. The entry A[0] now holds the result.
>
> For k > 1, we begin by choosing one element at random as above and we
>   now repeat the same process with n - 1 element sub-array A[1, n -1].
>   Eventually, the random subset occupies the slots A[0, k - 1] and the
>   remaining elements are in the last n - k slots.
>
> Intuitively, if all subsets of size k are equally likely, then the
>   construction process ensures that the subset of size k + 1 are also
>   equally likely. A formal proof for this uses mathematical induction -
>   the induction hypothesis is that every permutation of every size k
>   subset of A is equally likely to be in A[0, k -1].
>
> As a concrete example, let the input be A = <3, 7, 5, 11> and the size
>   be 3. In the first iteration, we use the random number generator to
>   pick a random integer in the interval [0,3]. Let the returned random
>   number be 2. We swap A[0] with A[2] - now the array is <5, 7, 3, 11>.
>   Now we pick a random integer in the interval [1, 3]. Let the returned
>   random number be 3. We swap A[1] with A[3] - now the resulting array
>   is <5, 11, 3, 7>. Now we pick a random integer in the interval [2,3].
>   Let the returned random number be 2. When we swap A[2] with itself the
>   resulting array is unchanged. The random subset consists of he first
>   three entries, ie., {5, 11, 3}.

Sorry for the long text; my questions are this

1. What is the key to efficiency they are referring to? Its not clicking in my head
2. What did they mean by "eventually, the random subset occupies the slots A[0, k-1] and the remaining elements are in the last n - k slots"
3. is there a clear reason why "every permutation of every size k subset of A is equally likely to be in A[0, k - 1]"?
4. Can you explain the theory behind the algorithm in clearer terms?
5. What is the return of the algorithm supposed to be?

thanks

Comment: (Too many questions here...) Do you understand what that line `A[i], A[r] = A[r], A[i]` is doing? It seems pivotal to this algorithm to me.

Comment: On 5: "The `return` statement returns with a value from a function. `return` without an expression argument returns `None`. **Falling off the end of a function also returns `None`**." ([The Official Pyhton Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)). So this returns and prints `None` (which, incidentally, you could have seen too if you run it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. an intuitive solution might be

```
def random_sampling(k, A):
    subset = []
    selected = set()
    for i in range(k):
        index = random.randint(0, len(A) - 1)
        while index in selected:
            index = random.randint(0, len(A) - 1)
        selected.add(index)
        subset.append([A[index]])
    return subset
```

but its not clear that every k subset has equal probability (because for the same k you may use different number of randoms on different ranges)

so a solution that fit the probability condition will be

```
import itertools as it
def random_sampling(k, A):
    index_posibilities = [i for i in it.combinations(A,k)] #very expansive action
    index = random.randint(0, len(index_posibilities) - 1)
    selected = []
    for i in index:
        selected.append(A[i])
    return selected
```

so the solution they gave makes sure you use the same procedure of randoms for every set of k elements without the brute force above

2. the order of the list is now, first k elements are these we selected, the rest of the list are the remaining items
3. this is the induction assumption, I assume that every set in length k-1 has the same probability and proof it for set of length k.
4. an efficient way to make sure the same probability for every k size sub set, is to do exactly the same steps to produce it
5. no return value because the list is being changed in the function is also changed in main, the subset is the first k elements of the list after the function being called